# How do I upgrade an SPFx web part to the newest SPFx version?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

I found a web part to show **and print** PDF docs from SharePoint, and it seems to support the swipe gesture too. The code is for SPFx v1.12. I'm thinking about upgrading to **v1.16** first.

What would I need to do? Is it complicated? Here's the link, just for reference --> [SPFx PDF web part code](https://github.com/adobe/PDF_WebPart_SharePoint).

Comment: Hi @Thomas, does my below response answers your question? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 3):

You can use CLI for Microsoft 365 to upgrade your SPFx project/solution to latest SPFx version.

You have to use [project upgrade](https://pnp.github.io/cli-microsoft365/cmd/spfx/project/project-upgrade/) command for the same like:

```
m365 spfx project upgrade [options]
```

Check below links for details steps for same:

1. [Upgrading SPFx solutions to the latest version using the CLI for Microsoft 365](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=jEJ_dxcEREA)
2. [How to upgrade your SPfx project to the latest version, and how to fix/avoid common issues](https://elischei.com/how-to-upgrade-your-spfx-project-to-the-latest-version-and-how-to-fix-avoid-common-issues/)